# problema al hacer una consulta usando inner join

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

tengo un problema al hacer una consulta usando inner join, cuando hago la consulta , los registros se multiplican por el numero de registros en la tabla.
**Tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Informes_tecnicos](
    [id_Articulo] [int] ,
    [id_informes] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [centro_publicacion] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [mes_publicacion] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ano_publicacion] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [descripcion] varchar (50) not null
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Articulos](
    [id_articulos] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Titulo] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Autor] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [palabras_claves] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [correo_elec] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    localizacion varchar (30) not null,
    [tipo] [varchar](30) Not NULL,
    [copia] [char](1) NOT NULL
)
create procedure [dbo].[ConsultarInformes]
as 
begin
select  Informes_tecnicos.id_informes, Informes_tecnicos.centro_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.mes_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.ano_publicacion,
         Articulos.Titulo, Articulos.tipo, Informes_tecnicos.descripcion
       FROM Articulos INNER JOIN Informes_tecnicos
       ON Articulos.tipo = Informes_tecnicos.descripcion;
END
```

**Esa tabla solo tiene 3 registro.**

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola.. sin ver los datos de origen y a lo que queres llegar va a ser dicifil ayudarte...

Comment: Necesitamos entender la estructura de ambas tablas. Aparte de eso, el "error" es claro, las condiciones del join no son suficientes para cruzar las filas en forma única

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo edite

Comment: @Lamak como lo harias?

Comment: Mejor compara por id
Articulos.id = Informes_tecnicos.id

Answer (score 0):

Debes comparar los ID's osea el campo que no se repite.
por lo que entiendo de tu código id_Articulo es un FK (Clave foranea), asi que quedaría así.

```
select  Informes_tecnicos.id_informes, Informes_tecnicos.centro_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.mes_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.ano_publicacion,
     Articulos.Titulo, Articulos.tipo, Informes_tecnicos.descripcion
   FROM Articulos INNER JOIN Informes_tecnicos
   ON Articulos.id_Articulo = Informes_tecnicos.id_articulos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Trata usando distinct en el select de tu procedimiento

```
select distinct Informes_tecnicos.id_informes, Informes_tecnicos.centro_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.mes_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.ano_publicacion,
         Articulos.Titulo, Articulos.tipo, Informes_tecnicos.descripcion
       FROM Articulos INNER JOIN Informes_tecnicos
       ON Articulos.tipo = Informes_tecnicos.descripcion;
END
```

Aunque lo ideal seria como comenta @Erick Zarate es que compares por id Articulos.id = Informes_tecnicos.id así solo selecciona aquellos artículos que estén ligados a un Informe técnico, suponiendo que puedas crear artículos pero que aun no sepas a que informe técnico pertenece, en ese caso no habría relación una tabla con la otra
 Y es recomendable que utilices llaves primarias y foráneas para que la relación sea mas clara entre las tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto

```
create procedure [dbo].[ConsultarInformes]
as 
begin
select  Informes_tecnicos.id_informes, Informes_tecnicos.centro_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.mes_publicacion, Informes_tecnicos.ano_publicacion,
         Articulos.Titulo, Articulos.tipo, Informes_tecnicos.descripcion
       FROM Articulos INNER JOIN Informes_tecnicos
       ON Articulos.id_articulos = Informes_tecnicos.id_Articulo;
END
```